# UICollectionViewCell inside UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I am trying to place `UICollectionView` inside `UICollectionViewCell`. I have prepared my cell in xib file using autolayout, same for cells inside collectionView.
But what about autolayout?

Some of my `UICollectionViews` inside my cell are different size that the others because of its content so I fail using `sizeForItemAt indexPath:` to calculate proper size.

Is there any fairly simple way to do this using autolayout, different from changing this main `UICollectionView` to `UITableView` with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as a `heightForRowAt indexPath:`?

EDIT:
To explain everything i've done so far to make this work i'll provide a cell layout:
[image]
and some algorithm to calculate cell's size:

First of all i declared an array of cells heights inside my `UIViewController` subclass like so:
`fileprivate var cellsHeight: [CGFloat] = []`.

After that inside `UICollectionView` delegate method `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` i am populating this array with height of each individual `collectionView` content size like so:

`let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell...`

```
if cell.collectionView != nil {
        cellsHeight.append(cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height)
    }
```

And then in inside `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` i am calculating each label size using `boundingRect` method, adding up some padding and previously fetched collectionView height.

But i think this is a pretty overkill.

Comment: Can you provide the reference image of layout?

Comment: I just did. Check it out.